# Iterate over a tree of folders and sub folders and find a specific file by name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am new to batch scripting. Basically I want to iterate over a tree of folders and sub folders and find a specific file by name.
Until now I have this :

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
for /F %%i in ('dir C:\Projects /s /b') do (

    Set originalFileName = %%~ni
    echo %originalFileName%
    )
pause
```

basically now I want to compare with a string and copy that file to another folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir C:\Projects /s /b /a-d') do if /i "%%~na"=="string" copy "%%~fa" "x:\another folder\"
```

Comment: I altered it to a case insensitive string compare.  Remove the `/i` if you need to compare the exact case.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another method to achieve the same aim, if only one `filename.ext` exists in the tree.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir "C:\Projects\filename.ext" /s /b /a-d') do copy "%%a" "x:\target-folder\"
```

Comment: Or, since the OP appears to want to compare the name only (without the extension), it could be `... in ('dir "C:\Projects\filename.*" ...') do ...`